# How to encapsulate a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, crash

I got a program with some threads created with boost::thread because it is a manager to start and control multiple gameservers for my game project.

The manager consists of one single application and my question is the following:

How to encapsulate a thread this way that if it crashes for example during a NULL Pointer exception or similar that the thread itself ends but not the whole program is crashed afterwards.

Comment: Why would you allow an unhandled exception in the first place?

Comment: Ofcourse I don't want to allow it but on a big project as a gameserver with multiple database connections, instances and external files misstakes can happen. And if I did a misstake in an update and missed that on testing period or similar I want atleast not all servers to crash at once.

Comment: Your question really is: "How can I write code to sanely handle a case that I didn't write code to sanely handle?" When you realize that that's the question, the answer should be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should absolutely make sure null pointer exceptions cannot occur in the code. This is a mandatory requirement.

Is there any way you could instead split your application into multiple communicating processes? That way if one of them crashes, the rest are unaffected.

Comment: Completely agree. We should always start with the premise that programs have to work properly, multi-threading or not. I've seen far too much of this `catch (...)` recently in library code aimed at 'keeping things going'

Comment: Yea ofcourse I am not planning to let it occur but it's going to be a big project and it can and will probably happen. 
In that case I will find and fix it.

I will wait for some other answers first. If there is a way to realize it within one application. If not I will have no chance but to follow your advice and create multiple processes.

Comment: This is just not something threads do. Threads share pretty much everything. If one thread runs amuck, the process context is toast. Threads must be fully cooperating and fully trusting.

Comment: David Schwartz is right. Think for example to the case of browsers (firefox, chrome), who run the flash plugin as a separate process to prevent the entire browser from crashing if the plugin crashes.

Comment: Okay thanks, I didn't knew then I will try to find a way to create multiple processes.

Comment: @user1356103 You should find a way to eradicate unhandled exception in your code. Creating more processes is not the answer to your question.